# Android Library back button

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, android-task

There is a android library. workflow like that:

> A1->A2-A3->Library activity->A3

I need to hide library activity when user click physical `back button`.
Also, the library activity saved some data, so that I cannot `destroy` or `finish()` the library activity.

> A1->A2->A3->lib--->return to previous A3

If user press `back button`, I want to skip the `library` activity and jump to `A2` from `A3` but not destroy the library activity because the library activity saved data that I need to use it again.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Try using stack

Comment: What kind of data is your library activity holding? Can you use a different way of saving your data instead of holding a whole activity in memory? and also there is a high probability of android OS killing your library activity when it is in the background.

Comment: my library need to capture three screenshot from the application. So that, it need to return to application from library activity when user want to capture the second and the third screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

You should override `onBackPressed` method in your activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed();
 //change your View from A3 to A2 
}
```

You can save data using `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: because it is the library, i cannot add the code in A3.

Comment: Thank you.
it is possible to save image using SharedPreferences

Comment: I am  not going to  recommend you to store image in Share preferences . And you should store that image to sdcard. And then store image path (from sdcard) into Share preferences.

Answer (score 2):

If currently visible activity is from the library, and you can not edit the code for it, then it is not possible to handle the backpress of the activity. However, If you are calling this library activity with an `Intent` from your Activity, What you can do is,
Write a class that `extends LibraryActivity` and call this activity instead. There you can override the `onBackPressed()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just make library activity  `android:noHistory="true"` in manifest. And save data you require some where else.